# UpdatePanel with repeater three levels deep

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to refresh a repeater within a webcontrol 3 levels deep w

```
<webcontrol1>
<UpdatePanel>

<webcontrol2>
<asp:LinkButton onclientClick="openDialog" onClick="FireArbitrararyEvent"/> 

<webcontrol3>
<div id="dialog">
<asp:Repeater/>
</div>

</webcontrol3>

</webcontrol2>


</UpdatePanel>

</webcontrol1>
```

The linkButton both opens the pana JQuery dialog which I'm expecting to show data immediately the panel is refreshed (in code-behind). The event listeners in level3 and level1 populate the repeater first then calls Update() on the panel respectively.

Currently the data only shows after closing and re-opening the dialog. How do I get to refresh the panel so that data is displayed first time round..

I have tried re-binding the repeater OnLoadComplete in level3 but this wont work 
I've tried the panel with UpdateMode as "Always" as all controls site inside the main panel on level1.

I have kept tried to keep this simple with only 1 panel but seem to be missing something with triggers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this post - [Can't get ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript in WebControl nested in UpdatePanel to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802506/problem-with-scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-in-webcontrol-nested-in-updatepa)

The issue was with getting the dialog to only pop-up after databinding, rather than just using `<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="ShowDialog" OnClick="FireEvents"/>`

Thanks!